# Reading multiple files in OpenCL kernel

Tags: java, opencl

I need to open multiple files for reading in OpenCL kernel. After opening them I need to read them all at the same time and add them to a single file or a string. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is likely possible. Have you search online to confirm this?

Comment: how about side-stepping the issue of reading and compile the kernel source into the file?  You could compile in either sourcecode or SPIR - whatever you deem more applicable. I myself use a mixture of bin2c - specifically this one https://github.com/gwilymk/bin2c  and amalgamate (which collects multiple source files into 1 file) https://github.com/nevion/Amalgamate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCL doesn't read or write files. There is no file access from an OpenCL kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unspecified, as this is not a OpenCL problem. You can make use of the Java file reading functionality.